# What is breadth of pertinence for [mercury]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I asked a [question](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/12069/) regarding a mercury thermometer, and it was retagged with [mercury](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mercury).
The reason why I didn't do that was because I thought the tag was to be used for dietary concerns of mercury — and not those concerning the physical properties of mercury in a medical instrument, or even probably not related to such at all.

Of course, I'd need to know this prior to providing information in the tag wiki.
What should I do?

- Rollback the edit?
- Edit the tag so as to make it applicable to my question?

Comment: You are supported by the fact that all other *mercury* questions are about dietary concerns. I'd therefore rollback the edit. You can also propose to rename *mercury* to *mercury-diet* or something so that it's usage becomes clear.